# symfony elastica bundle Exception when property of entity relation contain null

Tags: symfony, doctrine, foselasticabundle

I have a item entity, stock entity and color entity

Item has oneToMany stocks and stock have ManytoOne association with color

now I am mapping item entity and stocks with elastic search. I am mapping stocks as nested of item

but it gives an error when color_id is null in stock table, how I can solve this exception

item:
mappings:
id: { type: integer }
title: { index: analyzed, analyzer: autocomplete, search_analyzer: autocomplete }
description: { index: analyzed, analyzer: simple }
stock:
type: nested
include_in_root: true
properties:
id: { type: integer }
color: { type: object}

Type error: Return value of AppBundle\Entity\Stock::getColor() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Color, null returned

I am stuck from couple of days, if anyone have idea please share

Comment: Can you show the code of the Stock entity? It looks like the function getColor has a return type. I would guess it's somewhat like public function getColor(): Color If I guessed right you need to add a questionmark before Color to allow null as a returned value: public function getColor(): ?Color

Comment: thanks @Vyctorya it worked in case of null but having exception in case of actual color object as below Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Color could not be converted to string <code> /**
     * \@return Color|null
     */
    public function getColor(): ?Color
    {
        return $this->color;
    }</code>

Comment: You need to add a method to the Color entity: public function __toString() { return $this->NameOrSomethingElse; }

Comment: thanks @Vyctorya , it solved my problem but I don't what __toString()  does I am not aware about this, can you explain bit more.

Comment: If you have a form or something that displays a Stock entity and a related Color entity, Symfony/PHP/HTML does not know how to print the Color entity (print the id or another field value or a combination of multiple fields). That is why you get 'could not be converted to string'. If an entity has a __toString method the return value of that method will be printed and the error is gone.

Comment: If the error happens inside a form and you use an EntityType field: use the option 'choice_label' to configure the displayed string. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html